# pandas Dataframe convert rows into columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
0   65  70  77  255 66  71  77  255 67  72  78  255 66  71  77  255 65  69  76  255 65
1   166 171 175 255 171 175 178 255 175 179 181 255 181 183 185 255 184 185 186 255 183
2   63  67  70  255 72  75  78  255 86  89  91  255 101 102 104 255 110 110 112 255 119
3   51  51  59  255 45  45  53  255 47  47  55  255 52  52  60  255 57  57  65  255 64
4   75  78  87  255 72  75  84  255 70  73  82  255 68  71  80  255 68  71  80  255 67
5   255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 81
6   38  61  79  255 35  58  76  255 33  56  74  255 36  58  76  255 39  60  77  255 40
7   61  83  103 255 67  89  109 255 73  94  113 255 72  93  112 255 70  91  110 255 69
8   77  94  107 255 78  93  107 255 78  93  106 255 80  94  108 255 83  96  110 255 86
9   88  100 112 255 87  99  111 255 87  98  110 255 86  97  108 255 86  96  107 255 88
10  135 143 145 255 131 139 141 255 128 136 138 255 125 133 136 255 125 133 135 255 124
11  42  56  67  255 42  56  67  255 45  57  67  255 47  57  67  255 47  56  66  255 46
```

So I have this table which contents pixel values.
But I don't want 12 rows I want, There should be only one one row and one column means I want every values should be in one column and row.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

dataSet = []
for file in glob.iglob(r'Dataset\train\building\*.png'):
    img = Image.open(file)
    data = np.array(img)
    color_features = data.flatten()
    dataSet.append(color_features)

dfData = pd.DataFrame(dataSet)
n = 10000
dataDF = dfData.iloc[:, :n]
df_Data = dfData.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join).to_frame('new')
print(df_data)
```

Error

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found
```

please help...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

stack() -> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html

if string:

```
df2 = df.stack().groupby(level=0).apply(', '.join).to_frame('new')
    print (df2)
```

if int:

```
df2 = df.stack().groupby(level=0)
    print (df2)
```

---

You can flatten the values in column direction using ravel, is much faster. (If your data is in Series)

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ravel.html

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'new':df.values.ravel()})
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out!

Comment: Ok i tested in on jupyter notebook - if this raise error - just write